# How do I find Assembly Version of Calling Program?

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, version

I am using C# for this application.

I have a DLL that gets included within my application. From this DLL, I need to find the Assembly Version of the main program in which this DLL is included.

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()` does not return what I want. This returns the Assembly version of the DLL, not the main program.

How do I get the version information from the main program?

Comment: so you want to get the version number of the main program, but do this from the dll?  As in the version code will be in the dll?

Answer (score 22):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

is the right one.

Comment: I don't believe this is what OP is asking.

Comment: What about GetCallingAssembly?

Comment: `Config.AppOldVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();` Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Application.ProductVersion.ToString();
```

Comment: Applicable only to WinForms?